# how to apc case doctrine prepare query in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, apc

I used followed query in symfony2 i need to APC cache with doctrine how to use it... I tried follow apc cache but not got error.

```
$query =  $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare(
        "SELECT  V.id,
            (CASE WHEN "DAY"      THEN DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL start_date DAY ) 
                  WHEN "MONTH"    THEN DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL start_date MONTH )
                  WHEN "YEAR"     THEN DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL start_date YEAR ) 
             END as startDate
            ) `enter code here`
        FROM table_name V

         WHERE V.id = :id 
         ORDER BY date ASC"
    );
 $query->bindValue('id', $id)
 $query->setResultCacheDriver(new ApcCache())
 $query->useResultCache(true, 300, 'testcache');
 $query->execute();   
 $results = $query->fetchAll();
```

Comment: can you describe this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

$oResultSetMapp = new ResultSetMapping;
$oResultSetMapp->addScalarResult('id', 'id');
$oResultSetMapp->addScalarResult('name', 'name');

$sqlQuery = "SELECT T.id AS id, T.enable, T.name
    FROM table_name as T
    WHERE T.enable =  :enable";

$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
        ->createNativeQuery($sqlQuery, $oResultSetMapp)
        ->setParameter('enable', 1) 
        ->setResultCacheDriver(new ApcCache())
        ->useResultCache(true, 300, 'testcache');
$query->getResult();
```

Try this one, this will help you for sure.